# giving an array sum values in a for loop

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, for-loop, sum

Im having this annoying problem which not even my teacher can solve:/.
I want to fill an array with sum values from 1 to 100 this is my code:

```
while [ $i -le 100 ]
do
    #filling the list with the sums of i at the pos i
    sumList[$i]=$(echo $i | sum)
    echo $i |sum
    echo $sumList[$i]

    i=$(($i+1))
done
```

And for some reason it just fills all spots with the first value (00034     1)
I have no Idea what to do

Comment: and  00034 1 is the sum value of 0

Comment: What is `sum`? And `echo $sumList[$i]` should be `echo ${sumList[$i]}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's  [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net):

```
Line 6:
    echo $sumList[$i]
         ^-- SC1087: Use braces when expanding arrays, e.g. ${array[idx]} (or ${var}[.. to quiet).
         ^-- SC2128: Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element.
```

And with this fixed:

```
i=1
while [ $i -le 100 ]
do
    #filling the list with the sums of i at the pos i
    sumList[$i]=$(echo $i | sum)
    echo $i |sum
    echo ${sumList[$i]}

    i=$(($i+1))
done
```

You get all the different checksums and block counts that you'd expect:

```
32802     1
32802 1
00035     1
00035 1
32803     1
32803 1
00036     1
00036 1
32804     1
32804 1
[...]
```

Comment: inside double round parens, variable names are resolved, so `i=$(($i+1))` should be `i=$((i+1))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually examine the *output* from that script (removing the `echo $i |sum` line), it should become evident what's happening:

```
00034 1[0]
00034 1[1]
00034 1[2]
: : :
00034 1[100]
```

As you can see, the line `echo $sumList[$i]` is giving you `$sumList` (which is identical to `${sumList[0]}`)and `$i` *separately* and that's because, as per the `bash` documentation (my emphasis):

> Any element of an array may be referenced using `${name[subscript]}`. The braces are ***required*** to avoid conflicts ...

So, if you change that to the correct ${sumList[$i]}`, you'll see that you *are* indeed setting up the array correctly, you just weren't printing it correctly:

```
00034 1
32802 1
00035 1
: : :
08244 1
```

And, for what it's worth, there are *other* facilities in `bash` that will make your code more succinct, if that is your goal:

```
for i in {0..100}; do sumList[$i]="$(echo $i | sum)" ; done
IFS=$'\n' ; echo "${sumList[*]}"
```